# TTS in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to do text to speech on Chrome using JavaScript without any use of extensions or plugins?  For Firefox and IE it's working great.  I don't know how to do it for Chrome.  The hard part is to do it without any plugins and extensions in JavaScript?

Comment: How did you do it for Firefox and IE?

Comment: for firefox i used speak.js which is a open source n can be found here http://syntensity.com/static/espeak.html  n for ie i used activex..

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer, but if you need help with this we'll need to see some code. The question you're asking is "how do I integrate this particular library with my site" and it sounds like the library works but your integration does not. So update your answer to clarify that, throw your code up, and we can help you debug it. Without that, there's no telling what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery function to do speech to text (but not text to speech).

```
$(document).find(':input[type=text]').attr('x-webkit-speech', "x-webkit-speech");
```

BTW: this only works in Chrome and not any other browsers

Comment: i need only javscript as like speech.js...i m doing a project which should not have jquery

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you can't simply embed Javascript into a page to provide this at the moment. You'll need to develop an extension, as chrome provides APIs but they require extension-level permissions: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/new-text-to-speech-api-for-chrome.html

The only other alternative I see is completely writing your own library using the Google audio API (part of chromium) that converts text into speech using FFT synthesis, and that could take years. The documentation for that API is here: http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html

Comment: http://syntensity.com/static/espeak.html        have a look at this...it uses speak.js and it is working perfectly on chrome but when i download the source code from the site n while testing it its not working i donno whats wrong here..it is a opensource code.Help me with this

Comment: It looks to me like they've done exactly what the second answer was: they are using synthesis to create text-to-speech. You should probably edit your question to say that you're trying to use this specific library and it's not working for you, and you should also share with us how you are trying to use the code. It sounds like you have a problem in implementation.

Comment: It's also probably useful to note that this library you're using has been converted from C by converting it to LLVM bitcode then converting that to ECMAscript with https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki. This means you're essentially including a compiled library. Because of that, most of the work is done using http://syntensity.com/static/speakClient.js.